# Tealium custom container javascript running with page view trigger but not with click (add to cart tracking)

Tags: javascript, custom-tag, tealium

I have a custom container tag that I have stripped down to one console.log statement for debugging purposes.

When I set the rule for this tag to all pages or to specific pages and turn on Tealium debugging output, the console statement comes in the output right after

SENDING: [my tag's tealium UID]

After some work to set up the correct trigger that fires on a link event for add to cart, I can see it still SENDING: but I don't think the custom container tag's javascript runs and there is no console output from the tag.

I don't have an extension associated with this tag, although I am going to need one.